# python optparse, default values for optional options

Tags: python, optparse

This is more like a code design question.  what are good default values for optional options that are of type string/directory/fullname of files?

Let us say I have code like this:

```
import optparse
parser = optparse.OptionParser()
parser.add_option('-i', '--in_dir', action = "store", default = 'n', help = 'this is an optional arg')
(options, args) = parser.parse_args()
```

Then I do:

```
if options.in_dir == 'n':
    print 'the user did not pass any value for the in_dir option'
else:
    print 'the user in_dir=%s' %(options.in_dir)
```

Basically I want to have default values that mean the user did not input such option versus the actual value.  Using 'n' was arbitrary, is there a better recommendation?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use an empty string, `""`, which Python interprets as being `False`; you can simply test:

```
if options.in_dir:
    # argument supplied
else:
    # still empty, no arg
```

Alternatively, use `None`:

```
if options.in_dir is None:
    # no arg
else:
    # arg supplied
```

Note that the latter is, per [the documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/optparse.html#default-values) the default for un-supplied arguments.

Comment: thanks, sounds like a great suggestion!  can't believe i didn't think about None...

Answer (score 4):

How about just `None`?

Nothing mandates that the default values must be of the same type as the option itself.

```
import optparse
parser = optparse.OptionParser()
parser.add_option('-i', '--in_dir', default=None, help='this is an optional arg')
(options, args) = parser.parse_args()  
print vars(options)
```

(ps. `action="store"` isn't required; `store` is the default action.)

Comment: thanks, sounds like a great suggestion! can't believe i didn't think about None